# create my own event in J2ME

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, java-me

I'm making a small application that call a webservice async and I want to fire loading finish event when the response complete to be able to move to next form

How can I do it in a good way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating an interface and give it to my method , the interface change the value of the flag Boolean and call another method , that tell me that it has finished working so I can continues my working and also it is running in another thread

Answer (score 2):

Event firing in Java requires the following elements

- An event class to transmit information about the event
- An interface that describes how the bean will notify interested parties, known as listeners A data structure to track listeners
- Registration methods to add and remove listeners
- Code to fire the events

The event class will extend java.util.EventObject like this:

```
public class MyEventClass extends java.util.EventObject {
         //here's the constructor
         public MyEventClass(Object source) {
             super(source);
         }
}
```

The interface will look something like this:

```
 public interface MyEventClassListener {
     public void handleMyEventClassEvent(EventObject e);
}
```

The event source will look something like this:

```
public class MyEventSource {
  private List _listeners = new ArrayList();
  public synchronized void addEventListener(MyEventClassListener listener){
     _listeners.add(listener);
  }
  public synchronized void removeEventListener(MyEventClassListener listener){
    _listeners.remove(listener);
  }
  // call this method whenever you want to notify
  //the event listeners of the particular event
  private synchronized void fireEvent(){
    MyEventClass event = new MyEventClass(this);
    Iterator i = _listeners.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
      ((MyEventClassListener) i.next()).handleMyEventClassEvent(event);
    }
  }
}
```

The event listener will look something like this:

```
public class MyEventListener implements MyEventClassListener {
  // ... code here

  //implement the required method(s) of the interface
  public void handleMyEventClassEvent(EventObject e) {
    // handle the event any way you see fit
  }
}
```

You’ll need to register the MyEventListener object with the MyEventSource object by call its addEventListener method.

Good luck, be free to contact me for more details.

Comment: It is good to notice that java.util.EventObject is available through JSR 129 (Personal Basis Profile Specification), CLDC does not have it.

Answer (score 1):

To create an event in *J2ME* please try the following code :

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);

Event event = eventList.createEvent();
...
event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, summary);
...
event.commit();
```

For more details please refer to *JSR 75*.

Comment: LOL +1 for trying but I don't think this is the type of Event the OP is talking about :)